# Google Play - Compability error on publish game made in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, compatibility

how are you?

Well, i'm having some problems with my game in Google Play.
The question is: my partner and I published the app on Google Play yesterday, however, the app does not appear downloadable to ANY device, even if the minimum version is Android 2.2 (minimun SDK 8, target SDK 19). The message that the device is not compatible is always displayed. During development, we use a Nexus 4 for tests and everything works fine, but still cannot download the game on that phone on Google Play. The game was also tested in Galaxy S3, Nexus 5, XPeria U and Moto G working fine, which also can not download.

I changed everything in AndroidManifest.xml, like I see in various threads, but nothing changed. There's the content of my .xml

Please help, I don't know what to do.

Thanks!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.0.1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
            <receiver android:name="com.google.ads.InstallReceiver" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />  
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
</application>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you published the game like alfa or beta, you have to define a mail to test the app. But if you already did this, you can check the following issues:

1 - Check the device defined in registered mail;

2 - Compare the processor's version of device with processor's version on Unity that is ARMv7;